How can I force devtools.pprint to not colorize its output?
I have some code that uses devtools.pprint:
import devtools
devtools.pprint(my_dictionary)

How can I indicate to pprint that I do not want colorized output?  Setting NO_COLOR does not seem to have an effect:
NO_COLOR=1 ./my_program.py
# (produces colorized output)


PY_DEVTOOLS_HIGHLIGHT?

If you look at the implementation of pprint:
force_highlight = env_true('PY_DEVTOOLS_HIGHLIGHT', None)


def pprint(s: 'Any', file: 'Any' = None) -> None:
    highlight = isatty(file) if force_highlight is None else force_highlight
    print(pformat(s, highlight=highlight), file=file, flush=True)

you can see that it checks for PY_DEVTOOLS_HIGHLIGHT (either 1 or true, case insensitive, is "yes", anything else is "no"). Alternatively you can use pformat, which accepts the highlight argument, directly.
However, note that this removes all formatting (dim, bold, etc.) as well as the colours.
